# Does Nokogiri support RelaxNG compact syntax?

Tags: ruby, nokogiri

I am trying to validate against a RelaxNG compact syntax file using Nokogiri. Nokogiri throws a parsing error when I try this. I don't know if its the RelaxNG file or if Nokogiri lacks support for compact syntax. Does Nokogiri support RelaxNG compact syntax?

Comment: Note that you can always use [Trang](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang.html) to convert from compact syntax to xml-based RelaxNG, and then validate using Nokogiri with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Nokogiri only supports `.rng` files written in XML syntax. It doesn't support `.rnc` files written in compact syntax.

Comment: Have you a citation for this claim?